# Django logging initialization within a cron script

Tags: python, django

I have my logging configured in settings.py but I want to use it in a cron script. Since I haven't loaded any django stuff yet when the script starts, the logger doesn't work. 
I can get logging by starting my script with

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.DEBUG
```

but is there a better way to make sure the logging has been initialized?

Comment: Not really.  If you have command-line Django commands, why aren't you writing custom Django commands?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Biggest reason being I didn't know about them :). I will look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a better way to make sure the logging has been initialized?

Yes.  Write custom Django commands.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands